# Remainder function (%) runtime on numpy arrays is far longer than manual remainder calculation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

In the past few days I've been working on improving the runtime of a python function which requires many uses of the remainder function (%) among other things. My main test case is over an 80,000 element numpy array (monotonically increasing), with 10000 iterations, although I've tried on various other sizes as well.

Eventually I reached a point where the remainder function is a major bottleneck, and tried various solutions. This is the behaviour I found when running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.random.rand(80000)
a = np.cumsum(a)
d = 3
start_time1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    b = a % d
    d += 0.001
end_time1 = time.time()
d = 3
start_time2 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    b = a - (d * np.floor(a / d))
    d += 0.001
end_time2 = time.time()
print((end_time1 - start_time1) / 10000)
print((end_time2 - start_time2) / 10000)
```

The output is:

```
0.0031344462633132934
0.00022937238216400147
```

when increasing the array size to 800,000:

```
0.014903099656105041
0.010498356819152833
```

(For this post I ran the code only once for actual output, while trying to understand the issue I've gotten these results consistently.)

While this solves my runtime problem - I have a hard time understand why. Am I missing something? The only difference I can think of is the overhead of an additional function call, but the first case is pretty extreme (and 1.5x the runtime isn't good enough either), and if that were the case I would think that the existance of the `np.remainder` function is pointless.

**Edit:**
I tried testing the same code with non-numpy loops:

```
import numpy as np
import time


def pythonic_remainder(array, d):
    b = np.zeros(len(array))
    for i in range(len(array)):
        b[i] = array[i] % d

def split_pythonic_remainder(array, d):
    b = np.zeros(len(array))
    for i in range(len(array)):
        b[i] = array[i] - (d * np.floor(array[i] / d))

def split_remainder(a, d):
    return a - (d * np.floor(a / d))

def divide(array, iterations, action):
    d = 3
    for i in range(iterations):
        b = action(array, d)
        d += 0.001

a = np.random.rand(80000)
a = np.cumsum(a)
start_time = time.time()
divide(a, 10000, split_remainder)
print((time.time() - start_time) / 10000)

start_time = time.time()
divide(a, 10000, np.remainder)
print((time.time() - start_time) / 10000)
start_time = time.time()
divide(a, 10000, pythonic_remainder)
print((time.time() - start_time) / 10000)

start_time = time.time()
divide(a, 10000, split_pythonic_remainder)
print((time.time() - start_time) / 10000)
```

The result I get is:

```
0.0003770533800125122
0.003932329940795899
0.018835473942756652
0.10940513386726379
```

I find it interesting that the opposite is true in the non-numpy case.

Comment: I'm getting even more consistent results for the larger array. Even in that case I'm seeing a factor of 5 speedup. Really fascinating.

Comment: I expected `np.fmod` to fix the problem, but nope: https://ideone.com/1NYgfn

Comment: The workaround requires 3 temp arrays and two broadcasts to work. The % operator requires none of those things. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: since i appear to have forgotten to add this in my question - some of the things ive tried so far: using np.remainder, np.mod, %, running on different machines, running the 2 parts of the script seperately/in different order. ive even tried to run it as a for loop in c# (np.remainder was consistenly slower). ive gotten the ratio between the runs to chance on different machines, but seperating into parts has stayed consistenly better

Comment: You can edit your question any time. No need to do it for this though.

Comment: This indeed seems very weird. Do you need `a` after applying `np.mod`?

Comment: It's no miracle that python for loops are taking so long. The strange thing is that the difference shows up over the loop overhead even in that case

Comment: I suspect could be related to operator overloading in numpy.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a PyPI copy of NumPy 1.15.1. I get almost even timings for `%` and the manual computation.

Comment: I *can* reproduce a difference on a manual build from a clone of the NumPy git repo, though, on either 1.15.1 or master. I suspect there's a bad fmod involved.

Answer (score 12):

My best hypothesis is that your NumPy install is using an unoptimized `fmod` inside the `%` calculation. Here's why.

---

First, I can't reproduce your results on a normal pip installed version of NumPy 1.15.1. I get only about a 10% performance difference (asdf.py contains your timing code):

```
$ python3.6 asdf.py
0.0006543657302856445
0.0006025806903839111
```

I *can* reproduce a major performance discrepancy with a manual build (`python3.6 setup.py build_ext --inplace -j 4`) of v1.15.1 from a clone of the NumPy Git repository, though:

```
$ python3.6 asdf.py
0.00242799973487854
0.0006397026300430298
```

This suggests that my pip-installed build's `%` is better optimized than my manual build or what you have installed.

---

Looking under the hood, it's tempting to look at the [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src#L1926) of floating-point `%` in NumPy and blame the slowdown on the [unnecessary floordiv calculation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src#L627) (`npy_divmod@c@` calculates both `//` and `%`):

```
NPY_NO_EXPORT void
@TYPE@_remainder(char **args, npy_intp *dimensions, npy_intp *steps, void *NPY_UNUSED(func))
{
    BINARY_LOOP {
        const @type@ in1 = *(@type@ *)ip1;
        const @type@ in2 = *(@type@ *)ip2;
        npy_divmod@c@(in1, in2, (@type@ *)op1);
    }
}
```

but in my experiments, removing the floordiv provided no benefit. It looks easy enough for a compiler to optimize out, so maybe it was optimized out, or maybe it was just a negligible fraction of the runtime in the first place.

Rather than the floordiv, let's focus on just one line in `npy_divmod@c@`, the `fmod` call:

```
mod = npy_fmod@c@(a, b);
```

This is the initial remainder computation, before special-case handling and adjusting the result to match the sign of the right-hand operand. If we compare the performance of `%` with `numpy.fmod` on my manual build:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(1, 8000, dtype=float)
>>> timeit.timeit('a % 3', globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.3510419335216284
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.fmod(a, 3)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.33593094255775213
>>> timeit.timeit('a - 3*numpy.floor(a/3)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
0.07980139832943678
```

We see that `fmod` appears to be responsible for almost the entire runtime of `%`.

---

I haven't disassembled the generated binary or stepped through it in an instruction-level debugger to see exactly what gets executed, and of course, I don't have access to *your* machine or your copy of NumPy. Still, from the above evidence, `fmod` seems like a pretty likely culprit.