# Numpy: Find minimum of an expression over several parameters

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Is there a numpy way to get the minimum of an expression over many parameters without explicit loops?

```
#Randomly initialize samples
SAMPLES_NUM = 200
L = np.random.rand(SAMPLES_NUM)
q1 = np.random.rand(SAMPLES_NUM)
q2 = np.random.rand(SAMPLES_NUM)

#Make the data
X = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Y = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

#Calculate Z at (x,y) as the minimum of L[i]+x(q1[i]+q2[i]) + q2[i]y
#over all  i
```

I tried broadcasting:

```
Z = np.min(L + X*(q1+q2) +Y*q2)
```

But doesn't work because of broadcasting issues. Any ideas, or would I have to explicitly loop over all i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `meshgrid` versions, we could extend dims of `X`, `Y` and that brings in `broadcasting`, when those operations are performed with other inputs and finally using `min` along the last axis -

```
np.min(L + X[...,None]*(q1+q2) + Y[...,None]*q2,axis=2)
```

Comment: I actually need the meshgrids since I need to plot it after in matplotlib

Comment: Hello @Divakar, did you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242832/remainder-function-runtime-on-numpy-arrays-is-far-longer-than-when-taken-apa)? Your experience could be very valuable.